# Why am I not able to update test__user_id key in dictionary?

Tags: python

I am updating dictionary which containing data like,

```
dict_temp = {'description': 'hello', 'id': 683,  'status': u'pending', 'test__user_id': 430}
```

I have tried to update using dict_temp['test__user_id'] = 520 but not able to get updating dictionary.

I have search online for solution but not able to find any.

Hope if anyone have solution or suggestion for my issue.

[image: Issue]

As in above screenshot I can update values of description but not able to update value of test__user_id.

Comment: So you define the dictionary, then use the update, then print it, and it's not updating? Can you post the full snippet?

Comment: Please post the exact code you are executing.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried same above code in console of python and able to update `test__user_id` value successfully.

```
>>> dict_temp = {'description': 'hello', 'id': 683,  'status': u'pending', 'test
__user_id': 430}
>>> dict_temp['test__user_id'] = 520
>>> dict_temp
{'description': 'hello', 'id': 683, 'status': 'pending', 'test__user_id': 520}
```

Please share full trace-back if you still getting error.